# JMeter API set content-type

Tags: api, jmeter

I'm introducing in JMeter Pure java, how to set `content-type application/json` in httpSampler?

```html
// HTTP Sampler
        HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSampler.setDomain("localhost");
        httpSampler.setPort(8080);
  httpSampler.setPath("/posts");
        httpSampler.setMethod("POST");
        httpSampler.setName("API");

  String data = "{\"items\":[{\"stacking_limit\":null,\"id\":\"MLA60428354\",\"weight\":300,\"height\":20,\"only_rotate_axis\":null,\"width\":35,\"length\":45,\"quantity\":1}],\"pack\":{\"weight\":2000,\"height\":100,\"width\":100,\"length\":100}}";
  httpSampler.addNonEncodedArgument("", data, "");
  httpSampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);

  HeaderManager headerManager = new HeaderManager();
  Header h = new Header("Content-Type", "application/json");
  headerManager.add(h);
  httpSampler.setHeaderManager(headerManager);
```

When I send a post to the server, I check that headers contain `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, how to change it?

Comment: Your code looks fine. How did you check that header contained "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"? I.e. are you sure it's a `Content-Type` that arrived of your request, and not `Accept` or `Content-Type` of the response? Also does it work from JMeter UI (could be your server doing something weird)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The similar question has been asked in the discussion of the [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article, here is the essential part of the solution:

```
// Create Header Manager
HeaderManager manager = new HeaderManager();
manager.add(new Header("Content-Type", "application/json"));
manager.setName(JMeterUtils.getResString("header_manager_title"));
manager.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HeaderManager.class.getName());
manager.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HeaderPanel.class.getName());

// Create HTTP Sampler
HTTPSamplerProxy httpSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
httpSampler.setDomain("localhost");
httpSampler.setPort(8080);
httpSampler.setPath("/posts");
httpSampler.setMethod("POST");
httpSampler.setName("API");
httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

//Add HTTP Header Manager to HTTP Sampler    
HashTree httpSamplerTree = new HashTree();
httpSamplerTree.add(httpSampler, manager);
```